# how to extract parameters from Jmeter for web forms using redirection

Tags: redirect, webforms, jmeter

[image]Hi so my webform navigates from : http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/?t=aZCcbzidJJKfFgrkk1RYPH0zHTl+MtTuoGeiUw0hEw48nLZUoPrfntO29VV2daEiR3cPbu25/Xf2a3Q1UMZs1tAoUDti4wBVbYQbRHhhBDTt0Z1yTrWlkWKunP18DkVBkRSSVMdiHYyQ=&uniqueID=dGdck61pZFirpz9fA5FQZFhakSeoICZ9&dev=1696661 to 
http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/examstart.aspx
[image: image 1 instructions page request[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkvaL.png)
i.e. from the [image]instructions page to exam start page on the click of [![the exam start button. My Jmeter response during recording shows that the link: http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/examstart.aspx
accepts two parameters i.e. attemptid or recordid. These values are generated on the location parameter of the examstart screen when the user clicks on starts test and lands on exam page. My response for http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/examstart.aspx does not show the location parameter on JMeter. How do i extract attempt id or recordid dynamically in this case during redirection ?][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbQct.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbQct.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Expand the 3rd sample result from the top in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
2. Switch to "Response Headers" tab

   [image]

   there you should be able to see the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) header and you will be able to extract these `attemptid` and `recordid` values using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)

Comment: Hi i selected main and sub samples and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thankyou @Dmitri T. do you mind sharing your email address with me?